# Gather Addresses of all Static C Strings at Compile Time

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c++17

Let's say I have a function like

```
void foo(const char* bar, ...)
```

And it has been called in multiple places.

Is it possible to gather addresses of all static strings that are known at compile time in `main()`?

For example, `foo("abc")`, I want in `main()` to be able to get the address of `"abc"`.  If someone calls `foo(someVariable)`, the address of `someVariable` might not be known, and so it can be ignored.

Is it possible?

Comment: Note that `"abc"` can have different address than (an other) `"abc"`.

Comment: I am okay with different addresses even though the contents are exactly the same.  Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: You might create `operator ""_some_suffix` to register static c-string manually.

Comment: There are no facilities in C++ to gather all the strings; this is an implementation issue.  Your compiler *may* have some API for this or command line switches or `pragma`.

Comment: Many projects use a database of strings.  This is very useful when having to present text in different languages.

Comment: Any idea about GCC in particular?

Comment: @Jarod42  Thanks for your suggestion.  It is very close to what I want but apparently, the "registration" is done whenever operator"" is called, and for the same C string (with same memory address), it gets called multiple times if the string appears in multiple places.  Thanks for mentioning this operator, learning something new and useful!

Comment: @HCSF: Provided solution exposing my suggestion, with only one registration by similar string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you agree to use registration, you might do something like

```
// Would contain each registered string.
std::vector<const char*>& registered_vector()
{
    static std::vector<const char*> v;
    return v;
}

bool Register(const char* s)
{
    registered_vector().push_back(s);
    return true;
}

// Class which holds the unique pointer as buffer.
template <typename Char, Char... Cs>
struct static_string
{
    static constexpr Char s[] = {Cs..., 0};
};

template <typename Char, Char... Cs>
constexpr Char static_string<Char, Cs...>::s[];

// string literal operator templates are a GNU extension
// MACRO can replace the operator to avoid that extension.
template <typename Char, Char... Cs>
static_string<Char, Cs...> operator ""_ss()
{
    static_string<Char, Cs...> res;
    static const bool dummy = Register(res.s); // Register only once :-)
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
    return res;
}
```

And now, test it:

```
int main() {
    "Hello"_ss;
    "World"_ss;
    "Hello"_ss;
    "Hi"_ss;
    "42"_ss;

    for (const auto s : registered_vector()) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b84a121638dd7580)

Comment: I actually came up something similar but ugly (using a macro to create a scope with a local static variable to track whether it has been called once and without literal operator template).  Your solution is very elegant.  Taking advantage that local static variable will only be assigned once and so Register() won't be called again, it is a very smart trick!

Comment: FYI, it seems like C++17 includes literal operator template as I think GCC used to print warning when it is used.  Now with -std=c++17, it doesn't emit such warning.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to gather addresses of all static strings that are known at compile time in `main()`?

At compile time strings from other translation units are unavailable.

You can dump string literals from your executable or shared library using `readelf -W -p .rodata <executable>` command.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Technically, your answer is indeed the right answer -- no way to do so at compile time (so I realized I asked a dumb question).  If you don't mind, I would like to expand the question a bit -- when foo() is called, is it possible to map bar to the corresponding address of its entry in .rodata in a very fast manner (e.g. less than 10 ns)?  I know I can parse .rodata into a map (e.g. std::unordered_map, std::map) and then look up the map when foo() is called but it seems quit slow.

Comment: Actually playing around more with readelf more.  It seems like the runtime (virtual) memory address of each static C string is the beginning memory address of .rodata section + the offset stated in readelf -W -p .rodata output.  Am I right?

Comment: I also noticed some function names also are part of .rodata.  Anyway to filter them out?  Thanks in advance!